# How to disable swipe.js carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, swipe

I'm trying to responsively convert a list of images into a carousel. I am using the swipe.js (swipejs.com) libary as it's performs perfectly.

I want the carousel to be initiated when the body width reaches less than 540px but reversly if the window is resized to a body width that is greater than 540px this is reverted.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
    if(bodyWidth < 540){
        loadCarousel();
    }else if(bodyWidth > 540) {
        unLoadCarousel();
    }
});

function loadCarousel() {
        window.deviceSwipe = new Swipe(
            document.getElementById('device-slider')
        );
}

function unLoadCarousel() {

}
```

Now this is close to how I want it (I believe), my real question is, how do I unload(disable?) this carousel and remove the inline styles swipe.js includes?

I can use the following line to remove the styles but this seems like a bit of a bodge job.

```
$('#slider-container li, #slider-container ul, #device-slider').attr('style', '')
```

This also doesn't stop swipe.js from just re-applying the styles on window resize (even if the bodyWidth is greater than 540px for some reason).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See, there is a kill method now available for swipe2 branche: https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/blob/swipe2/swipe.js

Comment: Thanks roasted, I tried using the kill method but didn't have much luck(I don't think it works, my carousel was still able to function after being "killed"). I ended up just swapping the content dependent on viewport.width. In my mind this feels like a bit of a bodge and isn't really the method I would have liked, however time is against me and no one will the notice the difference.

Comment: Noooooo, I have this same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method called kill as deviceSwipe.kill()